# How to change "namedtuples" into classes in Python?

Tags: python

Can anyone give an example?

What's the difference between using variables in classes and in namedtuples?

Comment: `namedtuple` generates a class dynamically on the fly.

Comment: Since you apparently never got an acceptable answer, perhaps you could update your question and provide some additional information. One difference between between general class instances and a namedtuple instances is that the latter are immutable like tuples -- meaning you can't change the value of any of its attributes without replacing the whole structure.

Answer (score 9):

The return value of `namedtuple` ***is*** a class. No dark magic. You do not need to "convert" a namedtuple return into a class; it returned exactly that.

`namedtuple` creates a new class that inherits from `__builtin__.tuple`. When you call `namedtuple('Point', 'x y')(1, 0)`, you're getting is the tuple object `(1, 0)` with the following syntactic sugar:

- a `__dict__` mapping where `{'x': 1, 'y', 0}`
- two properties `x` and `y` that call `__getitem__(0)` and `__getitem__(1)` respectively.
- a `__repr__` method that returns `'Point(x=1, y=0)'`

Other than this, it's just a tuple object. Its attributes and number of attributes are immutable.

However, I suspect you mean you want to take `nametuple('Point', 'x, y')` and instead get:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

In this case you are misusing `nametuple`, and should instead be using `type`:

```
def init(self, x, y):
    self.x, self.y = x, y
Point = type('Point', (object,), {'__init__': init})
```

Comment: You are wrong. When you call `namedtuple('Point', 'x y')(1, 0)` you **do not** get tuple object. You get `Point` instance. Also there are no `__dict__` mappings. And `x` and `y` properties **do not** call `__dict__[..]`.

Comment: @akaRem WRT namedtuple('Point', 'x y'), it returns a class that inherits tuple, as I wrote. I'm not sure where you're disagreeing with me here. Please clarify?

Comment: @akaRem looking at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/collections/__init__.py) the field properties call \_\_getitem\_\_s, so you're correct there. \_\_dict\_\_, however, is definitely defined as a mapping of _fields to the tuple data.

Comment: from source `class {typename}(tuple): <..>  __slots__ = ()` - so, instance could not nave `__dict__` mappings. And later in code `__dict__` is declared as property `__dict__ = property(_asdict)` where `def _asdict(self):\n\t'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values'\n\treturn OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))`. So `point.__dict__` is not a mapping. It creates new OrderedDict instance at every `__dict__` request. Its like a patch for cases when you expect that object that has smth like `.x` should also have instance's dictionary.

Comment: I could be wrong in way I understand word `mapping`. I thihk that when we say that A is mappind for data B, we say that A points to B data without any additional object creation at every request.

Answer (score 3):

Very vague question.

I suppose that you mean constructions like

```
myPoint1 = namedtuple('myPoint1','x y')
```

and

```
class myPoint2(object):
    __slots__ = ['x','y']
    def __init__(self, x, y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

`myPoint1` is faster in access by index `my_point1[0]`, `my_point1[1]` (where `0` stands for `x`, and `1` stands for `y`). But it's slower in access by attr `my_point1.x`, `my_point1.y` because of double lookups and additional function executing (see source - it's well documentated about how does `namedtuple` work)

`myPoint2` is only accessable by attr `my_point2.x`, `my_point2.y`. And accessing by attr `myPoint2` is faster than accessing by attr `myPoint1`.

Also if you dont use `__slots__`, every instance would consume more memory because **dict** of attrs/methods is created for every instance (for dynamically tune them - add or remove attrs, fields, methods, etc), whether **slots** is created once for class only.

Shortly, `namedtuple` returns `tuple subclass` that commonly works as `tuple`, but which data is also accessable by specified attrs.

Answer (score 2):

I think OP wants to be explit about the class definition for a data structure which is currently a namedtuple.  `namedtuple([...], verbose=True)` is likely what you're looking for:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Pooper = namedtuple('Pooper', ('poop_length','poop_width'))
>>> Pooper(7.5, 1.5)
Pooper(poop_length=7.5, poop_width=1.5)
>>> Pooper = namedtuple('Pooper', ('poop_length','poop_width'), verbose=True)
class Pooper(tuple):
    'Pooper(poop_length, poop_width)'
    __slots__ = ()
    _fields = ('poop_length', 'poop_width')

    def __new__(_cls, poop_length, poop_width):
        'Create new instance of Pooper(poop_length, poop_width)'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (poop_length, poop_width))

    @classmethod
    def _make(cls, iterable, new=tuple.__new__, len=len):
        'Make a new Pooper object from a sequence or iterable'
        result = new(cls, iterable)
        if len(result) != 2:
            raise TypeError('Expected 2 arguments, got %d' % len(result))
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        'Return a nicely formatted representation string'
        return 'Pooper(poop_length=%r, poop_width=%r)' % self

    def _asdict(self):
        'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values'
        return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))

    def _replace(_self, **kwds):
        'Return a new Pooper object replacing specified fields with new values'
        result = _self._make(map(kwds.pop, ('poop_length', 'poop_width'), _self))
        if kwds:
            raise ValueError('Got unexpected field names: %r' % kwds.keys())
        return result

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        'Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.'
        return tuple(self)

    __dict__ = _property(_asdict)

    def __getstate__(self):
        'Exclude the OrderedDict from pickling'
        pass

    poop_length = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')

    poop_width = _property(_itemgetter(1), doc='Alias for field number 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

from collections import namedtuple as nt

```
human_nt = nt('Human_nt', 'name, age')
peter_nt = human_nt('Peter', 20)

class Human_cls (human_nt):
     def some_methods(self):
          pass

peter_cls = Human_cls(**peter_nt._asdict())
```

Comment: How exactly does this address the question, which is about the difference between variables in classes and in namedtuples?

Comment: I believed this was the question`s title: How to change “namedtuples” into classes in python?

Comment: One big assumption is that all elements of the class can be send to the constructor .. Not that good.